# Is orientation of Stokes theorem a convention?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, stokes-theorem, orientation

Is orientation of Stokes theorem, that is, right hand rule, a convention? Can we also choose the left hand rule? But will not it create problems in Physics where the sign of our physical quantity (which is derived from Stokes theorem) will depend on this convention?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is more or less correct. The left hand rule would be perfectly consistent if it was used in place of right hand rule in every context.

Some physical quantities (such as magnetic field) will reverse direction, but the means to measure them will also measure in the opposite direction, and all observable (classical) phenomena would remain the same without altering the laws of physics.

The mathematical underpinnings of this convention are a bit more subtle. In 3 dimensional euclidean space, proper vectors transform accordingly when the space is rotated about an axis or reflected about a plane (and various geometric operations such as vector addition, orthogonal projection, and dot product obey this symmetry). The cross product of two proper vectors or the curl of a vector field *do not* have this property. When reflecting about an axis, their direction is reversed. Such objects are known as [pseudovectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector). The right hand rule is a convention for describing pseudovectors.

Curls and cross products can be treated as a different type of object (sometimes called [bivectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector)), which can be though of as a surface area with an orientation along its boundary (or, algebraically, as an antisymmetric matrix in an orthonormal basis). These objects have their own transformation rules, and there is no need to introduce sign conventions.

In three dimensions, every surface area can be conveniently described by a normal vector, but doing this with bivectors come with some caveats:

First, the resulting vector does not transform correctly under reflection, instead transforming as a pseudovector.

Second, there is no obvious choice of normal vector, in that there is no correspondence between orientation around a surface and a normal direction. It is therefore necessary to choose a convention, such as right hand rule, and avoid reflections entirely (since RHR ceases to be consistent under reflection).

If you want to use Stokes' Theorem in more general contexts (such as on 4-dimensional manifolds, as in General Relativity), it's best to avoid pseudovectors entirely and keep a clear distinction between vectors, bivectors, etc. Without pseudovectors, this "generlized" form of the theorem has no RHR-esque sign conventions.

Comment: One of the definitions of magnetic field in free space is "force on a unit north pole". Here how can you justify your statement "the means to measure them will also measure in the opposite direction" ?

Comment: Also if we can use both LHR and RHR, wouldn't the surface integral be having two values? Or shall we need to put a minus before the line integral if we are using LHL?

Comment: Basically, all pseudovectorial quantities would have their signs reversed, but if every measurement consists of a set of scalars, then things would cancel. You could also consider that the laws of physics themselves have a symmetry under reflection. People in a reflected "mirror universe" would be using the LHR, but writing down the same equations (backwards) and predicting the same outcomes for the same experiments.

Comment: To your second comment, when computing magnetic flux through a oriented loop of wire, the RHR would be invoked both in determining the surface normal and in determining the direction of the magnetic field (both would flip). When calculating something like the induced current, the result would be the same.

Comment: @Joe: If you reverse everything, then north poles become south poles and vice versa.

Comment: If you define "north" and "south" in terms of the magnetic dipole moment (a pseudovector) then that would be the case.

Comment: For some clear diagrams showing this, see [Teaching Rotational Physics with Bivectors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.03560.pdf)